# Interpreting the VECM: which variable corrects towards which one?

Tags: interpretation, vector-autoregression, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I am trying to understand the vector-autoregressive error correction model, but I am having a hard time understanding the error correction part.

Imagine that we have a VAR(1) model of 2 dimensions:
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
\Delta Y_t\\
\Delta X_t\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\alpha_Y\\
\alpha_X\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\beta_Y & \beta_X\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
Y_{t-1}\\
X_{t-1}\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
\varepsilon_{Yt}\\
\varepsilon_{Xt}\end{array}\right).$$

How do I know which variable error corrects to which variable?

I hope the question makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha_Y\neq 0$, $Y_t$ adjust to the equilibrium between $Y$ and $X$ ($Y$ "error-crrects").
If $\alpha_X\neq 0$, $X_t$ adjust to the equilibrium between $Y$ and $X$ ($X$ "error-crrects").